# add scalefactor and offset to NetCDF

Tags: netcdf, scale-factor, offset

I am converting some NetCDF files from Float32 to either 16bit or 8bit to safe space on a server.
Since I Originally created these NetCDF using GeoTIFF´s this is where I apply the conversion before adding them into a new NetCDF file. This works without any problem.

The issue I have is that I need to add a scalefactor and offset using the ncatted unidata command. 
As far as I understand to add scale and offset information the following commands are used:

```
ncatted -O scale_factor,Variable,c,f,Value foo.nc
ncatted -O add_offset,Variable,c,f,Value foo.nc
```

However it just shows me the help or cheatsheet when I run it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bit late but it may be helpful for others:

```
ncatted -O -h -a add_offset,sst,o,f,21 $filename
```

Found [here](http://olgahernand.free.fr/gallery_scripts/html/bash/nco_exemple_ncks_ncecat_ncap2_ncwa_ncrename_ncpdq.html). It seems that you forgot options -h / -a, -O being used to specify "overwriting" of the file.